# Mongodb merge results from two collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two separate mongodb collections `search` and `objects` that logs some user actions like using search page and viewing object page on my website.
Both of coollections have user cookie stored the same way:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ac35499db5acdb1c8b4567"), 
    ...
    "user" : {
        "id" : "12007", 
        "cookie" : "LffDjUQHogfrihI2z/FlzQ", 
    },
    "createddate" : ISODate("2015-09-20T02:39:53.780+0000")
}
```

Now i need to count unique users in both collections day by day. 
I know how to count them in one collection:

```
db.objects.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id":{
            "$subtract": [
                "$createddate",
                { "$mod": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$createddate", ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00") ] },
                    1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                ]}
            ]
        },
        'users' : {$addToSet : '$user.cookie'},
        }
    },
    {$project: {_id : 0, date : '$_id', users : {$size : "$users"}}},
])
```

So there i get count of unique cookies day by day. The probjem is that not all people that made search go to object page (but some of them go) so i need to get unique set of cookies by two collections day by day. 
I can get daily arrays of unique cookies from each collection and merge and count them on application side but i'm sure it can be done on db side. Please help.

Comment: MongoDB does not support "joins" in any way. If you need this information to be unique from two sources then you need to combine into a single collection first. Really your application design should be aware of this and writing all the data you need to a single collection in the first place. Anything else is just a workaround and a headache. Fix the design. BTW. Just use `Date(0)` as you don't need the whole `ISODate` thing anyway. It's just a helper.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, Thank you for comment. Yes, i know that having single collection for this needs is the best, but now i cannot change db architecture and have to use two collections for that report. Maybe some kind of MapReduce can help? Also thanks for `Date(0)` it looks much better.

Comment: The fact still remains, "no joins here". As for mapReduce, there is a common misconception that this performs joins where it does not. There is only a special case where you can "merge" or "reduce" onto output in another collection as a result, but it is a special case that does not suit everyone, and still basically is writing out to another collection before you get results. Your question is basically unclear as to the format of both inputs and the eventual output you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to do separate mongodb queries and merge them on application level.

Comment: Yes but how do you merge them on application level?

Comment: You just take data from DB to your application and in some useful format like `array` or `object` and then use kind of `foreach` and keys and etc to create needed structure.

Comment: For anyone looking how to actually do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614520/two-separate-mongodb-collections-combine-the-results-to-loop-through-with-no-rel hopefully it helps someone.